# Does jQuery ready() fire after all JS files has been loaded/executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JS files directly executing functions.
It is done with the module pattern (described here: //http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth).
So this actually means we have an anonymous self calling function defining our object which all objects holds/encapsulates.

It seems that these self calling functions are not necessarily executed before jquery's ready function.

1. Is this true?

If we have several files with this pattern:

module_part1.js

```
    var MODULE = (function (my) {
    my.oneFunc = function () {
    // added method...
    };
      return my;
   }(MODULE));
```

module_part2.js

```
    var MODULE = (function (my) {
    my.twoFunc = function () {
    // added method...
    };
      return my;
   }(MODULE));
```

Can we be sure that on jQuery's read function the function `Module.twoFunc` is not undefied?

Comment: could you give an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition the `document.ready` executes once the DOM has loaded. The `<script>` element is part of the DOM. When the browser encounters a `<script>` tag it stops parsing the page and downloads and executes the script before continuing on the next element. So inside the document.ready event all scripts (that were part of the DOM in `<script>` tags) will be loaded.

Comment: is this also true if the script is referenced in the HTML's head area?

Comment: Yes, it is also true in this case. The browser doesn't make any distinction between the head or body sections when loading scripts. But due to the blocking nature I have already explained in my answer it is usually recommended to put your scripts at the end of the DOM. This way you don't even need to be wrapping them in any document.ready events.

Comment: I am assuming that there is even no difference between an inline script and  <script type="text/javascript" src="any.js"></script>

Comment: The difference is that a remote script will have to be downloaded with a separate HTTP request to the server unless already cached on the client.

Comment: Is there a clear rule of how scripts are being executed. Meaning for example. The first script tag's script will be executed even when second is inline? I just want to be sure that the problem I am facing is not related to such an issue.